# Harmonic compensation due to a non-linear load

Tags: current, sensing

I am doing a project on harmonic compensation due to non linear loads. My current at the source is non-sinusoidal due to non linear load. The current contains harmonics and i am using ACS712 current sensor for harmonic current measurement but i know ACS712 doesn't show harmonics and its output only shows main current.

What should I do to sense harmonic current for accurate display of non sinusoidal current waveform in my oscilloscope and to use this sensed current harmonics for microcontrollers?

Comment: What you are looking for is called "FFT". Convert your current readings to the frequency domain, that will tell you the current at any given harmonic.

Comment: According to the [datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/BreakoutBoards/0712.pdf), the ACS712 has a 80kHz bandwidth. What makes you think that it "doesn't show harmonics and its output only shows main current"?

Answer (score 0):

Your current sensor is not in fact looking at the "main current" (by which I presume you mean the fundamental frequency). Instead it is simply converting a measurement of current into a voltage. The resulting voltage waveform will contain the same spectral information as the current signal - in other words the voltage signal will have the same harmonics as the current waveform.

To analyse the level of harmonics in any signal, you need to look at the spectral content of the signal - how much power there is at any given frequency. This is achieved by converting the time domain signal to the frequency domain. Performing an FFT (Fast Fourier Transform) of the signal is one way to achieve this.

Once you have converted your signal to the frequency domain, you will be able to see exactly what harmonics are presented and at what strength.